# "await" like similar function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having the function which is wait for `sync` after that it will load the content. Below function is working perfectly in firefox but not working in IE11

```
//Working in other browser and inserting the multiple records but not in IE

async function setup()
{
    await Word.run(async(context)=> {

        for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var controler = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("myTag"+i);
            controler.load();
            await context.sync();
            controler.items[0].insertPargraph("Adding paragraph "+i);
        }
    }
    )};

}
```

For IE11, below function is working perfectly for inserting only one record

```
//Working in IE for the only one record
function setUp()
{
    Word.run(function (context){

        var selectedTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("myTag");
        context.load(selectedTag,'text');
        return context.sync().then(function()
        {
            controler.items[0].insertPargraph("Adding paragraph 0")
        });

    })
}
```

Now problem is I want to iterate the loop for the contents, I have written the return function inside the forloop that the reason it is not working

```
//Below function is not working
function setUp()
{
    Word.run(function (context){

        for (var i=0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var selectedTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("myTag");
            context.load(selectedTag,'text');
            return context.sync().then(function()
            {
                controler.items[0].insertPargraph("Adding paragraph 0")
            });
        }
    })
}
```

How to write the `await` function for IE11 browsers. I have tried the `goto Lable` function but that also not working.

Comment: Looks like you forgot `getByTag("myTag"+i);` and `insertPargraph("Adding paragraph "+i)` in third example. The **+i** part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `async` version uses `i` with `getTag` and when adding the paragraph, but your subsequent code example doesn't. It matters for the solution.

#### Common Ground

You can create a promise chain, similar to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43766002/157247) but different enough it might be hard to apply that to your case. Basically, you start with a resolved promise (`p`), then use `p = p.then(...)` to build the chain.

#### If you don't need to use `i`'s value

...then you can do it like this:

```
function setUp()
{
    Word.run(function (context){
        var p = Promise.resolve();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            p = p.then(function() {
                var selectedTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("myTag");
                context.load(selectedTag,'text');
                return context.sync().then(function()
                {
                    controler.items[0].insertPargraph("Adding paragraph 0")
                });
            });
        }
    })
}
```

#### If you do need to use `i`'s value

...then we need to bake it into the code since you have to use `var` (IE11 has `let`, but it doesn't have ES2015 semantics for `for` loops):

```
function setUp()
{
    Word.run(function (context){
        function doOne(index) {
            // We use `index` below
            var selectedTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("myTag" + index);
            context.load(selectedTag,'text');
            return context.sync().then(function()
            {
                controler.items[0].insertPargraph("Adding paragraph " + index)
            });
        }
        var p = Promise.resolve();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            p = p.then(doOne.bind(null, i));
        }
    })
}
```

#### Giving `setUp` a return value

Your `async` version assumes that `Word.run` returns a promise and that it expects its callback to return a promise. I can't find any documentation to support that, but then, the web documentation for this stuff appears to be truly amazingly bad.

**If** both of those assumptions are true, then to haev `setUp` return a promise, we'd only need to make small changes: `return` before `Word.run` and `return p;` at the end of the callback (see `***` comments);

```
function setUp()
{
    return Word.run(function (context){                      // ***
        function doOne(index) {
            // We use `index` below
            var selectedTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("myTag" + index);
            context.load(selectedTag,'text');
            return context.sync().then(function()
            {
                controler.items[0].insertPargraph("Adding paragraph " + index)
            });
        }
        var p = Promise.resolve();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            p = p.then(doOne.bind(null, i));
        }
        return p;                                            // ***
    })
}
```

But if `Word.run` doesn't return a promise, or doesn't expect a promise from its callback, that won't work and we have to create our own:

```
function setUp()
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {           // ***
        Word.run(function (context) {
            function doOne(index) {
                // We use `index` below
                var selectedTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("myTag" + index);
                context.load(selectedTag,'text');
                return context.sync().then(function()
                {
                    controler.items[0].insertPargraph("Adding paragraph " + index)
                });
            }
            var p = Promise.resolve();
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                p = p.then(doOne.bind(null, i));
            }
            p.then(resolve).catch(reject);                   // ***
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: If `setUp` is meant to be an `async` function, shouldn't it return a promise that is resolved only when all the internal promises have been resolved? Something like `return Promise.all(innerArrayOfPromises);`

Comment: @Terry: **If** `Word.run` returns a promise (Microsoft's documentation is so bad I can't tell if it does), then the `async` version does wait for it. I can't find any indication it does, but I'll update just in case. We wouldn't want `Promise.all`, no.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have tried your code it is working for the till fourth loop, for the fifth loop it is throwing  `ReferenceError: 'resolve' is undefined` error

Comment: @mkHun: I take it you mean you've tried to use the last example. All due respect, you must have copied it incorrectly, as `resolve` is definitely in-scope and not `undefined` in the code above.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are trying to achieve is to chain the `sync()` calls together so that the callback in `Word.run` only resolves when everything is syncd. You can do this using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to generate a promise resolving when all provided promises have resolved.

```js
function setUp() {
  Word.run(function(context) {
    const promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var selectedTag = context.document.contentControls.getByTag("myTag");
      context.load(selectedTag, 'text');
      let p = context.sync().then(function() {
        controler.items[0].insertPargraph("Adding paragraph 0")
      });
      promises.push(p);
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
}
```

Comment: Technically speaking, since `promises` is never reassigned, you can safely use `const promises`... ;) same thing for `p` and `selectedTag`.